# Maclaurin series $y=(\sin(2x))^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to expand to Maclaurin series $y=(\sin(2x))^2$.

I've got it to $y=(1/2)-((\cos4x)/2)$.

What is next?

Comment: ==1== cos(x) = 1 - x²/2 + x⁴/4! - x⁶/6! + ... 
-------> cos(4x) = ∑(-1)^n * (4x)^(2n) / (2n)!, n = 0 to n = ∞ 
------->  1/2 - cos(4x)/2 = ½ - ½∑(-1)^n*(4x)^(2n) / (2n)! 
------->  this only really affects the n = 0 term, you get ½ - ½ = 0 
------->  sin²(2x) = ½∑(-1)^(n + 1)(4x)^2n / (2n)!, from n = 1 to n = ∞

Comment: Use the taylor series of $\cos(t)$.

Comment: Is ==1== right? (In the 1st comment)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin^22x=\frac12(1-\cos 4x)=\frac12\left(1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(4x)^{2n}}{(2n!)}\right)$$

and I think your expression is correct (hard to read it without LaTeX...)

Comment: Sorry for not using LaTeX, thanks!

Comment: @Brown, don't forget: (1) Upvote all the answers you found helpful, and (2) **accept** the answer that you found best for you. The second one you can wait a while to do it